# Using Camera in Cordova / Phonegap bypass "Use photo" in iOS possible

Tags: ios, cordova

When using Phonegap/Cordova to acuire an image from the camera, the camera-app is started correctly. However when taking a photo, the photo is not return immediately, one must first press "use photo" in order to get the image.

Is it possible to bypass the "use photo" step and get the photo directly?

This is observed on iOS.

Comment: Did you find anything?